# pg_dump stops with this message free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, pg-dump

We need to create a logical backup of the database, and we initiate the process with the following command:
`pg_dump -U postgres -Fc -Z6 -f /tmp/backup.dump DOC`
After some time, we encounter the following error, and the logical backup process is interrupted:
`free(): double free detected in tcache 2`

We tried to repeat the process with the following command:
`pg_dump -U postgres DOC > /tmp/backup.sql`
`free(): double free detected in tcache 2`
However, we still receive the same error.
There is sufficient disk space available, and the physical copying from one host to another is successful.   How can we resolve this error and obtain a logical backup?
What could be the issue?

When i start pg_dump with --verbose:
pg_dump: reading indexes of table "public.schemastorage"
pg_dump: capturing indexes in partitioned tables
pg_dump: reading extended statistics
pg_dump: reading constraints
pg_dump: reading triggers
pg_dump: reading rewrite rules
pg_dump: reading policies
pg_dump: reading row-level security policies
pg_dump: reading publications
pg_dump: reading publication members
pg_dump: reading subscriptions
pg_dump: reading large objects
pg_dump: reading dependency information
pg_dump: saving encoding (UTF8)
pg_dump: saving standard_conforming_strings (off)
pg_dump: saving search_path =
pg_dump: saving database definition
free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Postgresql version 11.15
Yes, pg_dump and postgresql server are from the same source

Comment: That looks like a bug in PostgreSQL. If you are not using a fork, please report it to the project. To make the bug report useful, you'd have to provide steps to reproduce, for example with a `pg_basebackup` of a slimmed-down copy of your cluster.

Comment: Does it still happen without -Z6? Without -Fc? With -s?

Comment: What is `select version()`?  pg_dump -V?

Comment: version of pg_dump is 11.15

Comment: 1) What is Postgres version? 2) Are the `pg_dump` and `postgresql` server coming from the same install/source? **Add answers as update to question not in comments**.